# JSON with Latin 1 encoding - error in Swift, works in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, json, swift

I am writing an app that one of my colleagues wrote in Obj-C but I am doing it in Swift, to learn (without looking at his source code). However, I hit a brick wall. Examining his source code I realized I am doing basically the same thing in Swift but in my case it simply doesn't work.

I am trying to load a JSON which is encoded in Latin 1 (ISO8859-1 if you like). Now, I know JSON should be encoded in UTF but there is nothing I can do about this. So to be able to work with it, I need to convert it to UTF8 and then feed it to the JSON processing function:

My code in Swift (doesn't work; ***JSON Error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)***):

```
var err: NSError?
let stringifiedData: NSString! = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
var json: NSDictionary!

if (stringifiedData != nil) {
    if var jsonCorrectedData = stringifiedData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonCorrectedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
    }
}
if (err != nil) {
    println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
    return
}
```

Colleague's code (does work):

```
NSString *strData= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSData *parsedData = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:parsedData options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *result = json[@"data"];
```

Both NSData's (Swift and Obj-c) print the exact same result:

```
7b0a0922 64617461 223a7b0a 09092273 74617475 73223a22 30222c0a 0909226d 656e7361 6a65223a 224c6f20 73656e74 696d6f73 2c20706f 7220656c 206d6f6d 656e746f 20656c20 73657276 6963696f 206e6f20 7469656e 6520636f 62657274 75726120 656e2074 75207a6f 6e612e0a c2bf4465 73656173 206c6c61 6d617220 61204d6f 64656c48 6f676172 3f220a09 7d0a7d
```

Now this would translate to (according http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx):

> {     "data":{        "status":"0",       "mensaje":"Lo sentimos, por el momento
>   el servicio no tiene cobertura en tu zona. Â¿Deseas llamar a
>   ModelHogar?"  } }

I am suspicious about the `Â` char (?). Seems like it is throwing off the JSON serialization in Swift but not in Obj-C. I have spent all day on this but I have no idea how to solve this. Does anybody have some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe an little/big endian issue? Could you compare `correctedData` in Obj-C and Swift byte by byte? Not only the descriptions?

Comment: @Sulthan No, I don't think it's an endian issue (or at least I cannot see how it could be). The data are the same. So my Swift NSData jsonCorrectedData == Obj-C NSData parsedData. Those bytes I put there are actually the NSData instances in HEX, they are the same

Comment: The problem is `0a`(LF) before `Â`. JSON doesn't allow LF in string.

Comment: @rintaro How come it works in obj-c? Any idea how to process the latin-1 encoded json to avoid things like this?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work even in Obj-C. Your JSON is corrupted. Maybe, you should consult with someone who generated this JSON.

Comment: @rintaro In theory it is not even a valid JSON as a valid one should be encoded as UTF as far as I know. However, as I mentioned above, it does work in Obj-C with the code I provided. Not quite sure how it is possible but it does...